# Why tcpdump does not work with -w flag?

Tags: linux, networking, tcpdump

So I have a network that I want to scan with `tcpdump` and dump the captured traffic into a file.

Let's say I try:

```
sudo tcpdump net 192.168.0.0/24
```

`tcpdump` will start and will show the traffic in the network. However, if add the `-w` flag.

```
sudo tcpdump net 192.168.0.0/24 -w mypcap.pcap
```

`tcpdump` just hangs and that its, it does not even time out. Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`man tcpdump`, or more equivalently, `man tshark` writes,

> If the `-w` option is specified when capturing packets or reading from a capture file, `tshark` [*or `tcpdump`*] does not display packets on the standard output. Instead, it writes the packets to a capture file with the name specified by the `-w` option.

To apply this to your situation, the command hasn't hung but is busy writing packet data to the file you specified.

The documentation continues,

> If you want the packets to be displayed to the standard output and also saved to a file, specify the `-P` option in addition to the `-w` option to have the summary line displayed [...]

and then goes on to offer other alternatives,

> specify the `-V` option in addition to the `-w` option to have the details of the packet displayed, and specify the `-O` option, with a list of protocols, to have the full details of the specified protocols and the top-level detail line for all other protocols to be displayed. If the `-P` option is used together with the `-V` or `-O` option, the summary line will be displayed along with the detail lines.

It's always worth reading the documentation to check such apparent issues.